# GUI Not Responding Pyqt

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt5, qthread

I'm trying to run a YOLOv4 model with webcam on GUI but i always get a "not responding window". It shows the first frame of webcam and it freezes.
This is my Thread class:

class VideoThread(QThread):

```
change_pixmap_signal = pyqtSignal(np.ndarray)

def __init__(self):
    ...

def run(self):
    self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while self._run_flag:
        ret, img = self.cap.read()
        if ret:
            self.change_pixmap_signal.emit(img)
    self.cap.release()

def stop(self):
    ...
```

It can detect the frame successfully but last 2 line on the below code make the GUI freezed. This is my main class:

class App(QWidget):

```
def __init__(self):
    ...
    self.image_label = QLabel(self)
    ...
    self.thread = VideoThread()
    self.thread.change_pixmap_signal.connect(self.detection)
    self.thread.start()

def closeEvent(self, event):
    ...

@pyqtSlot(np.ndarray)
def detection(self, img):
    original_image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    image_data = cv2.resize(original_image, (input_size, input_size))
    image_data = image_data / 255.

    images_data = []
    #for i in range(1):
    images_data.append(image_data)
    images_data = np.asarray(images_data).astype(np.float32)

    batch_data = tf.constant(images_data)
    pred_bbox = infer(batch_data)
    for key, value in pred_bbox.items():
        boxes = value[:, :, 0:4]
        pred_conf = value[:, :, 4:]

    # Perform NMS after YOLOv4 inference
    boxes, scores, classes, valid_detections = tf.image.combined_non_max_suppression(
        boxes=tf.reshape(boxes, (tf.shape(boxes)[0], -1, 1, 4)),
        scores=tf.reshape(
            pred_conf, (tf.shape(pred_conf)[0], -1, tf.shape(pred_conf)[-1])),
        max_output_size_per_class=50,
        max_total_size=50,
        iou_threshold=iou,
        score_threshold=score
    )
    pred_bbox = [boxes.numpy(), scores.numpy(), classes.numpy(), valid_detections.numpy()]
    image = utils.draw_bbox(original_image, pred_bbox)
    # image = utils.draw_bbox(image_data*255, pred_bbox)
    image = Image.fromarray(image.astype(np.uint8))

    image = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(image), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) 
    qformat=QImage.Format_RGB888
    
    outImage=QImage(image,image.shape[1],image.shape[0],image.strides[0],qformat)
    #BGR>>RGB
    outImage=outImage.rgbSwapped()
    
    self.image_label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(outImage))
    self.image_label.setScaledContents(True)
```

What should i do for this freezing GUI?

Comment: I didn't run it but usually it means you have to run some code in separated thread.

Comment: Which parts should i seperate?

Comment: Please don't create a new post that is basically the same as a [closed one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67369517/pyqt5-gui-not-responding). Try to improve *that* post instead and notify us about it in comments, so that we can consider reopening. Also, check that you're properly [formatting the code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362).

Comment: I created this post for giving you more codes than that post. This post is more explanatory to get some helps.

Comment: @serimgençaslan please read [ask], review the [tour] and provide a [mre]

Comment: @serimgençaslan Note: You should not create a new post to update your post since one edition is enough, it is annoying that you create a new post for those cases.